# How To Setup Qpid with Queues using qpid-config.json

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

Is it possible to define what queues and topics should exist in `qpid` using `qpid-config.json`. I am using `qpid 7.1.0.`

How would I do this in a config file?

Answer (score 2):

Qpid Broker-J has two levels of configuration, broker-wide configurations and virtual-host specific configuration. Each virtual host has its own set of queues and topics (or - more properly - exchanges), so the queue and topic definitions are in the virtual host config.

If you are just using the default configuration you get with Broker-J then it will create a virtualhost named "default" with the configuration stored as JSON in the file system (e.g. in work/default/config.json ).

Probably the best way to see how the queue and exchange configuration is stored in that file is to first create queues/exchanges through the [Management UI](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.1.0/book/Java-Broker-Management-Channel-Web-Console.html), and then look to see what the config looks like.  (Note that you shouldn't manually edit the config while Qpid is running... as it will likely overwrite it, however you can update the config while Qpid is stopped and it will pick up the changes).

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a go.